# Calculating potential due to point charge using properties of Harmonic functions (Solutions of Laplace's Equation )

Tags: electrostatics

Property says:- [V stands for potential, *O* for origin]

*The value of V at a point $\vec{r}$ is the average value of V over a spherical surface of radius R centered at $\vec{r}$.*

Mathematically,

> $$V(\vec{r}) = \frac{1}{4\pi R^{2}} \oint_{sphere} Vda\ \ \ \ \ \ ... eq.1$$

Suppose there is a charge *q* on *Z*-axis at distance $z_{0}$ from O. I want to calculate the potential at *O* using above property. If I choose a spherical surface, not including the charge, that is, surface with radius *R* < $z_{0}$, the answer is

> $$\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_{0}} \frac{q}{z_{0}}\ \ \ \ \ \ ... eq.2$$

But if a surface is chosen such that it includes the point charge, that is, a surface with *R* > $z_{0}$, the answer is

> $$\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_{0}} \frac{q}{R}\ \ \ \ \ \ ... eq.3$$

But isn't this wrong, after all, the potential at *O* due to a point charge located at (0,0,$z_{0}$) is simply the expression in $eq.2$.

What misconception have I developed?

References : Introduction to Electrodynamics by Griffiths ($4^{th}$ edition) >  Chapter 3 (Potentials) > Section 1.4 (Laplace's Equation in 3-Dimensions) and Problem 1

Answer (score 1):

You didn't do the surface integral correctly for either case.
In each case V varies over the surface, leading to a complicated integral.
 .

Comment: No! the integrals are quite clumsy but the answers come out to be neat. By the way, the answers are for sure correct.

Comment: "The answers are for sure correct."  "But isn't this wrong?"  Are they right or wrong?

Comment: They are right as per the solution manual